# How I can protect user transaction when deploying new release in production server?

Tags: tomcat7

I have a J2EE(JSF+Primefaces+Postgresql+Hibernate) web application[Link](http://www.askkuber.com)

I will want to protect user transaction(Will not lost any transaction due to server restart) when ever i will deploy any new release in production server or server id down for few minute for maintenance.The exact scenario is 
Let us suppose i am a user and creating a Stock portfolio and i am in between of creating this portfolio now suppose admin restart Tomcat server ,so how can Admin will make sure that the transaction done by any user will not lost due to this restart of server.

Comment: if the transaction fails then data will "roll back" to state before the transaction, that's why it is called transaction.

Comment: But i want if user in between creating a portfolio it will be saved in database or user will get a message in website that we are going to start in few minute please do not make any transaction or if user will click on button then this message will display to user ?